# Defining a Keras layer by summing parts of another layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Can anyone give me a suggestion: when running the following code, an error occurs (I use TF as the backend)

```
inputs = Input(shape=(100, 1, ))
lstm = LSTM(3, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
outputs = 2*lstm[:, :, 0] + 5*lstm[:, :, 1] + 10*lstm[:, :, 2]
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, y)
```

The error is

> TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: Tensor("add_1:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly,

```
outputs = Lambda(lambda x: 2*x[:, :, 0] + 5*x[:, :, 1] + 10*x[:, :, 2])(lstm)
```

should do what you are looking for.

```
In [94]: model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

In [95]: model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         (None, 100, 1)            0
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_12 (LSTM)               (None, 100, 3)            60
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)            (None, 100)               0
=================================================================
Total params: 60
Trainable params: 60
Non-trainable params: 0
```

For example, to simply add two inputs,

```
In [143]: inputs = Input(shape=(2,))

In [144]: outputs = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0] + x[:, 1])(inputs)

In [145]: model = Model(inputs, outputs)

In [146]: model.predict(np.array([[1, 5], [2, 6]]))
Out[146]: array([ 6.,  8.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct, and thanks for your help. When I change the code as you told above. another error is occurred about data shape. The error is:  ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lambda_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 100, 1) @fuglede

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your `x` or `y`; as illustrated by the summary, the model figures out the shapes of the arrays at each layer on its own. What are the shapes of `x` and `y`?

Comment: The different is when using Lambda the output shape of layer Lambda is (None, 100), but the shape is (None, 100, 1) when using TimeDistributed(Dense()), which is running well without any wrong.@ fuglede

Comment: @JMZhou: Then just throw in a `Reshape((100, 1))(outputs)`.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not clear what you told. How to throw in ?

Comment: ohoh!  I get it. 'Reshape' is a layer in Keras.  Thank you so much.@fuglede